# conversion from string to int while passing as a parameter in a method

Tags: c#

I have a method that inputs an integer as a parameter in a class -

```
public string OddNumbers(int input)
```

and in my main program, I am trying to accept an integer from the user, through a textbox, and I am converting the input string to integer while passing the parameter -

```
string odd = od.OddNumbers(int.Parse((TextBox1.Text))).ToString();
```

and I am getting the following error:

> "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format."

I tried different methods of converting the integer to string, but results in the same error, for example:

```
string odd = od.OddNumbers(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text));
```

Any help in pointing out where I am going wrong?

Comment: One reason for FormatException in this case would be that an empty string is being passed to int.Parse. This can happen if nothing is entered into the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

What input are you trying to enter?

I would try a couple of things.

1)  Run a trim on the input before passing it into the parse command.  This will make sure there are no empty spaces at the end of the number.

2)  If you are trying to accept a decimal, make sure you use double.

Comment: i am trying to input just a plain whole number

Comment: You are probably going to have to toss it in the debugger and check to see what the actual value of TextBox1.Text is.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work assuming that the user enters a valid integer in the textbox:

```
int i = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
string odd = od.OddNumbers(i).ToString();
```

Another possible way to handle this is to use the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method:

```
int i;
if (int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out i))
{
    string odd = od.OddNumbers(i).ToString();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(TextBox1.Text + " is not a valid integer");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, i tried your code, but still getting the same error.

Comment: @user672096, what's the value of `TextBox1.Text` when you step through your code? If it is `null` or an empty string you will get this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Do not nest functions, it makes code incredibly difficult do debug and maintain.

```
    int Number;

    if (int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out Number) == false)
    {
        // parsing error
        Number = -1;
    }

    string odd = od.OddNumbers(Number);
```

Comment: Thanks guys,  i did a stupid mistake - i had a textbox to capture the number, but didnt trigger the event by doing the computation of finding whether the entered integer is odd or even. once, i put the method inside the click event of a button, i am getting the desired results.  Thanks for all the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Once i put the method inside an click event, which finds out whether the input integer is odd or even, it gave me the desired result.  thanks for all the inputs.